# A word to describe sets of something divided into three equal parts as per "quartile" (fourths) or "quintile" (fifths)

Tags: mathematics, category, statistics

I am looking for a word that describes a set of numeric values divided into three equal, ordered parts.

For example, "quartile" refers to subsets of a set that has been divided into four equally-size parts sorted in order (i.e., the first quartile is the set of the first 25% of lowest values, the second contains the next-higher subset of 25% of the values, etc.). Likewise, "quintile" refers to subsets of a set divided into five equally-size ordered parts.

"Thirds" is not exactly what I am looking for since dividing something into thirds does not necessarily connote  an ordering of items in the set.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile, which includes both answers already given here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a ***tertile***.

Wiktionary:

> **[tertile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tertile)**
> *Noun*
>
> (statistics) Either of the two points that divide an ordered
> distribution into three parts, each containing a third of the
> population.
> (statistics) Any one of the three groups so divided.
> The first tertile results include January through April's revenues.

Comment: I like tertiles.

Answer (score 1):

Also **tercile**

> (statistics) Either of the two points that divide an ordered distribution into three parts, each containing a third of the population.
> (statistics) Any one of the three groups so divided.
> [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tercile)